# mysql installed but not working

Tags: mysql, centos

i installed mysql mysql-devel mysql-server by removing older one. i used commands as

```
# rpm -e mysql mysql-server mysql-devel --nodeps
# yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
#  /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

it says

```
-bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

then i tried locating it, so i did

```
# locate mysqld
/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld
/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/K36mysqld
/etc/rc.d/rc1.d/K36mysqld
/etc/rc.d/rc2.d/S64mysqld
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S64mysqld
/etc/rc.d/rc4.d/S64mysqld
/etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S64mysqld
/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/K36mysqld
/usr/bin/mysqld_multi
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
/usr/bin/mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldumpslow
/usr/libexec/mysqld
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqld_multi.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqld_safe.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mysqldumpslow.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/safe_mysqld.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mysqld.8.gz
/var/lock/subsys/mysqld
/var/log/mysqld.log
/var/run/mysqld
```

so after searching found [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=176353) page so i did

```
rpm -V mysql
```

but it says

```
# rpm -V mysql
package mysql is not installed
```

also did

```
# service mysqld start
```

but output was

```
  mysqld: unrecognized service
```

so i tried to install it again by `yum install mysql` but this time output is

```
 yum install mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Setting up Install Process
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

please guide me where i am doing wrong. what should be correct approach to do this?

**EDIT**
I am on centos5
and

init.d have mysql file see this

```
# cd /etc/init.d/
[root@domain init.d]# ls
crond      dc_server  haldaemon  httpd      iptables  iscsid   kudzu         mcstrans    multipathd  netconsole  netplugd  rawdevices  restorecond  sshd
dc_client  functions  halt       ip6tables  iscsi     killall  lvm2-monitor  messagebus  mysql       netfs       network   rdisc       single       syslog
```

i did

```
# service mysql start
Starting MySQL SUCCESS!
[root@domain init.d]# mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
[root@domain init.d]# mysql -u root -h localhost
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

**EDITED**

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23
perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5
php-mysql-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3
MySQL-devel-5.1.48-1.glibc23
```

every time i do `yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel` it installs only mysql-server and mysql-devel not the mysql. and if i alone do `yum install mysql` it says:

```
 yum install mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Setting up Install Process
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

and

```
#  yum whatprovides '/usr/bin/mysql'
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysql



mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386 : MySQL client programs and shared libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysql



MySQL-client-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 : MySQL - Client
Repo        : smartfile
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/mysql
```

***EDIT AGAIN***

```
# yum remove MySQL-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: MySQL-server
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Package(s) MySQL-server available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

whenever i do `yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel` it says

```
# yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Setting up Install Process
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package mysql-server is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package mysql-devel is obsoleted by MySQL-devel, trying to install MySQL-devel-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package mysql-devel is obsoleted by MySQL-devel, trying to install MySQL-devel-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MySQL-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.48-1.glibc23 set to be updated
---> Package MySQL-server.x86_64 0:5.1.48-1.glibc23 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                  Arch                               Version                                        Repository                             Size
========================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 MySQL-devel                              x86_64                             5.1.48-1.glibc23                               smartfile                             9.4 M
 MySQL-server                             x86_64                             5.1.48-1.glibc23                               smartfile                              19 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total download size: 28 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

means only mysql-server and mysql-devel not the third one that is mysql.

***UPDATED***

```
 yum --disablerepo=smartfile install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.i386 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6 for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6 for package: mysql
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
---> Package mysql-devel.i386 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-devel for package: mysql-devel
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.i686 0:0.9.8e-20.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2 for package: openssl
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT) for package: openssl
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3 for package: openssl
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3(k5crypto_3_MIT) for package: openssl
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3 for package: openssl
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-20.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: krb5-devel for package: openssl-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-devel.x86_64 0:1.6.1-62.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux-devel for package: krb5-devel
--> Processing Dependency: e2fsprogs-devel for package: krb5-devel
--> Processing Dependency: keyutils-libs-devel for package: krb5-devel
---> Package krb5-libs.i386 0:1.6.1-62.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1 for package: krb5-libs
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1(KEYUTILS_0.3) for package: krb5-libs
--> Running transaction check
---> Package e2fsprogs-devel.x86_64 0:1.39-33.el5 set to be updated
---> Package keyutils-libs.i386 0:1.2-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package keyutils-libs-devel.x86_64 0:1.2-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libselinux-devel.x86_64 0:1.33.4-5.7.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol-devel >= 1.15.2-1 for package: libselinux-devel
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libsepol-devel.x86_64 0:1.15.2-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                         Arch                               Version                                      Repository                        Size
========================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql                                           i386                               5.0.77-4.el5_6.6                             base                             4.8 M
 mysql                                           x86_64                             5.0.77-4.el5_6.6                             base                             4.8 M
 mysql-devel                                     i386                               5.0.77-4.el5_6.6                             base                             2.4 M
 mysql-devel                                     x86_64                             5.0.77-4.el5_6.6                             base                             2.5 M
 mysql-server                                    x86_64                             5.0.77-4.el5_6.6                             base                             9.8 M
Installing for dependencies:
 e2fsprogs-devel                                 x86_64                             1.39-33.el5                                  base                             637 k
 keyutils-libs                                   i386                               1.2-1.el5                                    base                              18 k
 keyutils-libs-devel                             x86_64                             1.2-1.el5                                    base                              27 k
 krb5-devel                                      x86_64                             1.6.1-62.el5                                 base                             1.9 M
 krb5-libs                                       i386                               1.6.1-62.el5                                 base                             668 k
 libselinux-devel                                x86_64                             1.33.4-5.7.el5                               base                             149 k
 libsepol-devel                                  x86_64                             1.15.2-3.el5                                 base                             192 k
 openssl                                         i686                               0.9.8e-20.el5                                base                             1.4 M
 openssl-devel                                   x86_64                             0.9.8e-20.el5                                base                             1.9 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================================================================
Install      14 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total size: 31 M
Total download size: 15 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                         | 4.8 MB     00:00
(2/2): mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                  | 9.8 MB     00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                    10 MB/s |  15 MB     00:01
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt from install of openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/ca.1ssl.gz from install of openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/req.1ssl.gz from install of openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/x509.1ssl.gz from install of openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686 conflicts with file from package openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

***FINAL UPDATE***

```
# yum remove openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Package(s) openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: Which version of CentOS is this?  Where is your /etc/init.d-directory?

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: What Shane said.

Comment: @Kvisle please see my edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server, trying to install MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-5.1.48-1.glibc23.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

It looks like you downloaded the `MySQL-server` package from the homepage and installed with `rpm -ivh`. Verify with:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep MySQL
```

If you want to install `mysql-server` from the repository (base, epel, ...), you must uninstall the `MySQL-server` first by executing:

```
# yum remove MySQL-*
```

and then:

```
# yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
```

The init script from `MySQL-server` package is `mysql` instead of `mysqld` from `mysql-server`. The hint for you is type some characters (`/etc/init.d/mys`) and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: when i install mysql it automatically install mysql-server in place of mysql. see my edit.

Comment: I didn't see your edit. Append the output of `rpm -qa | grep -i mysql`?

Comment: apologies. see its there now.

Comment: `# yum remove MySQL-server`?

Comment: yum remove MySQL-* this removes devel and server both and then when i install using your command it only install devel and server not mysql it self. and when i do service mysql start it gives success but nothing on command mysql.

Comment: Show the updated output?

Comment: see the output of yum whatprovides '/usr/bin/mysql'

Comment: No. Show the output prove that the `MySQL-*` (include `MySQL-devel-5.1.48-1.glibc23`) are uninstalled successfully and _"when i install using your command it only install devel and server not mysql it self"_?

Comment: please see the output again.

Comment: `yum --disablerepo=smartfile install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel`?

Comment: thanks for looking again. please see the output. updated

Comment: `yum remove openssl-0.9.8e-20.el5.i686` and try again with `.x86_64` extension for all packages `yum --disablerepo=smartfile install mysql.x86_64 mysql-server.x86_64 mysql-devel.x86_64`.

Comment: yum remove command's output is there updated, but your second command did wonder for me. Thanks alot for giving time into this and helping me out of all this.

Comment: The lesson is you should disable (`enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/<name>.repo`) the unusual repo (remi, smartfile, ...) and only enable when necessary `yum --enablerepo=<repo_name> ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have installed MySQL-devel and MySQL-server manually from the rpms and are keeping you from installing mysql.

Better of remove those packages with

```
#yum remove MySQL-devel MySQL-server
```

and install it again with

```
#yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-devel
```

Also please post the output of both the commands above, that would help us to help you.

**EDIT**

The smartfile repository .. try disabling it ? with

```
#yum --disablerepo=smartfile
```

Comment: sorry, saw that you already removed the two packages, edited my post in accordance.

Answer (score 1):

You start the MySQL-server by running:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Normally, the MySQL-client is in the package named `mysql` in the os-repository:

```
# yum install mysql
```

But since that's not the case for you, I suspect you may have installed a different package.

Can you try:

```
# yum whatprovides '/usr/bin/mysql'
```

It should give you a list of packages that provide you the MySQL-client.

Comment: thanks for the reply but please sir see my question. i already tried this but it says nothing to do.

Comment: I apologize, updated

Comment: see the output of yum whatprovides '/usr/bin/mysql'

Answer (score 1):

First remove what you have:

```
yum remove mysql-server 

yum remove mysql
```

Then install :

```
yum install mysql-server 

yum install mysql 

yum install mysql-devel



service mysqld start
```